# How do you find first visible element with jqlite under AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, autofocus, jqlite

So, I have the following Angular directive to autofocus first `input` field on the current page of my Ionic application. It works great when the first field isn't hidden. But, if it's hidden by `ng-hide`, logic fails. So need to modify the element selector to find just for visible elements in my directive.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                element.find('label')[0].focus(); 
            }, 150);
        }
    };
});
```

Using above directive on a `form` element as follows,

```
<form name="signinForm" ng-submit="signinForm.$valid && doSignin(credentials)" novalidate focus-me>
```

So how should I change my jQLite find query to just look for the visible element? The find lookup is limited by tag name as per docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
element[0].querySelector('input:not(.ng-hide)').focus();
```

jQLite only allows selecting by tag name. So we can use the pure Javascript version i.e. `querySelector` along with using `:not` selector.

See a working example below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
          element[0].querySelector('input:not(.ng-hide)').focus();
        }, 150);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form focus-me ng-app="myApp">

  <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-show="false" />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-show="true" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />

</form>
```

Comment: In my case, its not the input that has ng-hide class. An outer div has it. But this answers the question asked. Thanks.

Comment: Sure @NiravGandhi. You can similarly use the same with the outer `div` like so: `element[0].querySelector('div.foo:not(.ng-hide)').querySelector('input').focus();` where I'm assuming your parent `div` has a class `foo`. :-)